# sharepoint media webpart cannot play when using ip address to access the server

Tags: javascript, jquery, sharepoint-2010

For example:

my server url is : http://myserver:10000, and when i access this address. everything is okay,media webpart can play correctly.

but when i change the way, http://192.168.1.100:10000,the webpart cannot play,the error message is Media failed to load.

is there anything I need to configuate or something else i'm wrong?

[image: this is the error screen]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Interesting.

What says your AAM configuration for this SharePoint instance? Perhaps it's an issue caused by a wrong map?